# Set callback function using unique_ptr of another class

Tags: c++, c++11

I am in need to implement a callback method using a unique_ptr of another class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    void Show(void) {}
};

class B
{
public:
    void SetCB(std::function<void(void)> callb);
private:
    std::function<void(void)> cb;
};

void B::SetCB(std::function<void(void)> callb)
{
    cb= callb;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a1 = std::make_unique<A>();
    std::unique_ptr<B> b1 = std::make_unique<B>();
    b1->SetCB(&a1->Show, a1.get());
}
```

I am getting compilation error:

```
$ c++ -std=c++14 try68.cpp
try68.cpp: In function 'int main()':
try68.cpp:28:29: error: no matching function for call to 'B::SetCB(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::unique_ptr<A>::pointer)'
 b1->SetCB(a1->Show, a1.get());
                             ^
try68.cpp:28:29: note: candidate is:
try68.cpp:19:6: note: void B::SetCB(std::function<void()>)
 void B::SetCB(std::function<void(void)> callb)
      ^
try68.cpp:19:6: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided

                 ^
```

Is it not possible to set a callback methods using unique_ptr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda, it will work like a charm:

```
b1->SetCB([&](){a1->Show();});
```

You may want to `move` the callback as well:

```
void B::SetCB(std::function<void(void)> callb)
{
    cb = std::move(callb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - please explain that do we need to move the callback as well as you have stated "may want to move" - why?

Comment: You don't have to move it, but if you have a callback more complex, with states and other things, there is no need to copy it when you can simply move it at a lower cost.

Comment: Just a another questions what if we have arguments to be passed using std::placeholders ?

Comment: The `move` won't actually save anything if the states are not sophisticated.  For example, moving a pointer or an int or a float won't do anything special.  But for more complex states, like a string or a vector, then a move is of potential benefit.

Comment: I think @Eljay summed it well!